# Посчитать средний бал в html таблице

Tags: javascript

Хочу подсчитать средний бал в столбцах и строках таблицы. Нашел такое решение, но не работает как надо так как ориентировано на то что будет таблица без названия столбцов и без пустых ячеек. Помогите пожалуйста изменить так что бы считало пропустив наименования столбцов и если ячейка пустая, то ее пропускало в подсчетах.

```js
(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("votes-table");
  var row = table.rows;
  // store columns sums
  var cols = Array.from({length: row.length + 1}, () => 0);
  for (var i = 0; row.length > i; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = n = 0; j < row[i].cells.length; sum += n, cols[j] += n, j++) {
      n = +(row[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
    }
    row[i].insertCell(j)
    .innerHTML = "<b>" + (sum / row.length).toFixed(1) + "</b>";
    // set column values
    cols[cols.length - 1] += (sum / row.length -1);
  }
  // set column averages
  table.insertRow();
  var lastrow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
  // set `len` to `len = cols.length` to include average of averages
  for (var i = 0, len = cols.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var html = "<b>" + (cols[i] / len).toFixed(1) + "</b>";
    td.innerHTML = html;
    lastrow.appendChild(td);
  }
})();
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="votes-table">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Вопрос1</th><th>Вопрос2</th><th>Вопрос3</th><th>Вопрос4</th><th>Вопрос5</th><th>Вопрос6</th></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>4</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте проверку, является ли значение ячейки числом, и выполняйте сложение только если является.

```js
let a =[1,'123','name',2,3,4,5,6,7];
let sum = 0;

a.forEach(i=>{
  let number = parseFloat(i);
  if (!isNaN(number)){ sum += number; };
});

console.log(sum);
```